# Are there hidden prepositions in these sentences?

Tags: predicative-complements, linking-verbs

- *My shoes are* [of] *the wrong color.*
- *This new wallpaper is* [of] *an odd pattern.*

At first, one could say these are noun phrases functioning as predicate nominatives; however, the awkwardness in meaning suggests that a preposition was omitted and the subject complement is actually an adjectival prepositional phrase. Is this the case? If so, when is the omission allowed?

Comment: The only hidden preposition I see is "on".

Comment: what do you mean by "the awkwardness in meaning"? how are these examples awkward similarly awkward?

Comment: Could you clarify your meaning? None of these sentences read as awkward to me, and none of them require a preposition. In fact, inserting *of* makes each sentence more awkward!

Comment: "My shoes are the wrong color" appears the same construction as "My shoes are green". No awkwardness or missing pronoun there.

Answer (score 0):

“Of” is not simply redundant, it changes the meaning slightly. “Of” indicates that the object *belongs to a certain category*, undesirable in the given context.

Not merely a random wrong (or odd) item — an item of the wrong *kind*.